Finite shape of universe and Lorentz Boost
In the context of special relativity, if we consider the universe as a finite solid cube of length
, where the coordinates

x and

+

x+L represent the same point (indicating periodic boundary conditions), does the size of this "universe" change for a moving observer due to length contraction?

You don't need periodic boundary conditions for this. Suppose you had a cube the size of the observable universe. What would its length be in the frame of a moving observer?

It would contract by 1 over gamma right?

This topology is called a torus.

Another way to view this is to realise that there is a privileged inertial frame orthogonal to the periodic directions.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153137/2451

If you're going to consider the entire universe, there's no sense in restricting the problem to special relativity.
